# TimeGetTime of iOS

Tags: ios

I am writing an application where I require the SystemTime i.e. the time elapsed since the system was started. Do we have any API availble in iPhone SDK which can be used in an iPhone application?
There is an API TimeGetTime() available on Windows Mobile.....do we have corresponding API on iPhone OS?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: So the time since the last boot of the device? Or just the Device's time?

Comment: NSTimeInterval ti = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] systemUptime];

Comment: the time since the last boot of the device. Thanks